# FTPS client behind a proxy server using apache commons net

Tags: java, ftps

Our network team only allow us to connect to our third party client thru proxy server.
Is there a way to add a proxy server to FTPS client of apache commons net?
If it is not possible, can you tell a way on how to do it.

By the way here's the code that is working outside of the company network

```
String server = "ftp.xxxx.com";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String remoteFile = "xmlSR.xml";
    String localFile = "c:/downloadedfile.xml";
    String protocol = "TLS"; // TLS / SSL
    int timeoutInMillis = 3000;
    boolean isImpicit = false;

    FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol, isImpicit);
    client.enterLocalActiveMode();
    client.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
    client.setActivePortRange(50000, 50200);
    client.setDataTimeout(timeoutInMillis);
    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(
            new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    client.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());

    try {
        int reply;

        client.connect(server);

        client.login(username, password);
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        client.execPBSZ(0);
        client.execPROT("P");

        System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

        reply = client.getReplyCode();

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            client.disconnect();
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        client.listFiles();

        boolean retrieved = client.retrieveFile(remoteFile,
                new FileOutputStream(localFile));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (client.isConnected()) {
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("# client disconnected");
        client.disconnect();
    }
```

even we tried to add some system property for proxyHost and proxyPort

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "yyyy.com");
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyHost", "yyyy.com");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "yyyy.com");
```

error message

```
Could not connect to server.
java.net.UnknownHostException: ftp.xxxx.com
at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1202)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:969)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)# client disconnected

at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:285)
at com.ti.itg.peit.bom.TestingApache.main(TestingApache.java:44)
```

Thank you very much.

Gerald

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn, we are using http proxy server to access external sites or outside of the company.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible..see the link below....

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/ProxySelector.java

Well using Apache's common lib to access FTP using proxy server, please set the `RemoteVerificationEnabled` to false after creation of FTPClient object.

eg:

```
FTPClient fc = new FTPClient();  
fc.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
```

You can use `java.net.Proxy` class which is for Java 1.5 and above, this
is used to set or unset the Proxy per connection basis

By using the `java.net.ProxySelector`, will determine a Proxy for each Connection.

Comment: Hi Kumar, the code that we have is properly selecting the proper proxyserver but still it can't connect to the ftps server. I have attach a code that is working outside of our company network.